# There seems to be a one to one association for [associations] and [model-associations]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/associations) has

> Associations typically refer to relationships between models in ORMs
>   such as ActiveRecord. [Presumably the ActiveRecord gem which is used
>   in the Ruby on Rails framework, rather than the Active Record design
>   pattern]
>
> Typically associations are classified based on the number of
>   associated models:
>
> one to many: one of the models stores the ID of the other
>
> one to one: models (which 'belong to') each store the ID of the one
>   associated model (which 'has many')
>
> many to many: the models are linked via a join table in the database
>   which may (called sometimes 'has many through') or may not (called
>   'has and belongs to many') be a model itself

The tag [model-associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-associations) has

> Models can associate in three main ways: one to many, one to one, and many to many.
>
> This is tagged primarily in Ruby community. Models can associate in
>   three main ways: one to many, one to one, and many to many.

I can't see any difference between the two descriptions, or the questions asked in the two tags. Should they be merged? If so, I think model-associations should be the preferred tag, as it's less ambiguous.